# Why am I getting syntax error of bracket?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following sql query:

```
\
(
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Everything seems correct. but dont know why this error?

Comment: `join BAAN1.baandb.dbo.ttcedi702200 Baan2 join [M3].[v850_Staging] Mthree on` the first join is missing an `on`, and you already have an alias `Mthree`

Comment: Why are you using LTRIM, RTRIM and a hard-coded collation everywhere? This will cause a *lot* of performance problems. And syntax errors, as it's way too easy to miss parentheses

Comment: All those operations prevent the database from using any indexes. Clean the data *before* querying it and make sure all tables use the same collation. At the very least use `TRIM` instead of `LTRIM(RTRIM())`. This won't fixe the perf problem but at least it will reduce the noise

Comment: If you added some formatting to your SQL, and didn't over use parenthesis (`()`) you would easily spot the issue (and in fact likely it would not exist).

Comment: In addition to other comments there's no need to, nor should you, use 4-part names

Comment: Maybe the OP is using a cross server query, @Stu .

Comment: possibly @Larnu - I was about to say there would be at least one different server name, then I saw there was, on same line - yet another reason for consistent formatting :)

Comment: The `RTRIM` is honestly completely pointless. SQL Server ignores trailing spaces for equality comparison. `'abc' = 'abc '` = TRUE. As for the leading spaces, if you want values to be equal where one has leading spaces and one doesn't, I would suggest that either you have a data integrity issue (and the values should either both have the leading spaces, or should not) or you should have calculated column in your table which is trimmed and indexed instead; and you use those columns as your `WHERE`/`ON` criteria.

Comment: Using `int` as primary/foreign keys instead of varchar avoids many problems: no leading/trailing spaces problem, no upper/lower case problem, no collation problem, no formatting problem.

Comment: So where's the rest of the query? The error message is complaining about line 16, but there's only 9 lines in the question's code.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer. Rather it demonstrates what happens after considering all the comments. Here is your query after editing and formatting for readability. Warning - DISTINCT is often a kludge to cover up a logic or schema fault.

```
select distinct Baan1.t_pono, Baan1.t_oqua, Baan1.t_eono, 
       Baan1.t_odat, Baan2.t_bano, Baan2.t_orno, Baan2.t_send, Baan3.t_cuno 

  from BAAN1.baandb.dbo.ttdsls04020 Baan1 
  join [M3].[v850_Staging] Mthree on
       Mthree.PONum1 collate DATABASE_DEFAULT = Baan1.t_eono collate DATABASE_DEFAULT

  join BAAN1.baandb.dbo.ttcedi702200 Baan2 
       <see anything wrong here?>

  join [M3].[v850_Staging] Mthree on
       Mthree.PONum1 collate DATABASE_DEFAULT = Baan2.t_bano collate DATABASE_DEFAULT

  join BAAN1.[baandb].[dbo].[ttcedi010200] Baan3 on 
       Mthree.Relation collate DATABASE_DEFAULT = Baan3.t_reno collate DATABASE_DEFAULT

<lack of ORDER BY clause is usually a fault>
<I added a statement terminator - which is a good habit you should develop
;
```

Notice that columns from Mthree are not used in the select list. Notice also that alias MThree is defined TWICE. It is odd that a "staging" table (view?) in one database is used to relate rows between tables in another database. Seems much more work is needed that goes beyond basic syntax issues.